# What's the difference between useState(function_name), useState(function_name()), useState(()=>function_name()) and useState(()=>function_name)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function `createHiveBackground` returns an array of objects that I want to assign to a state. Later in my application I'm going to use `setHive` to change some values of the array. What is the difference between these?

```
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground);
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground());
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(()=>createHiveBackground);
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(()=>createHiveBackground());
```

If I use `useState(createHiveBackground)` it seems to work properly.

If I use `useState(createHiveBackground())` each time I change a value with setHive the function is called again.

If I use `useState(()=>createHiveBackground)` TypeError: hive.map is not a function (seems like the function is not being executed).

If I use `React.useState(()=>createHiveBackground());` it seems to work properly.

Can some clarify what is the difference between all these options and what is the best for my case?

Comment: Make sure you know what an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is (no rocket science there) - i.e. you need to be familiar with that syntax. Then it is kind of simple to read those statements and understand the differences + combine that with official documentation (see Dennis's answer)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences are between:

- **Value type**: Function/Array (Function's return type).
- **Initial type:** Normal/Lazy

```
// Lazy assign the return value of the function
// Both are equivalent as First-class functions (check the reference)
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground);
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(() => createHiveBackground());

// Assign the return value from the function
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground());

// Lazy assign the function
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(() => createHiveBackground);
```

*References:*

- [useState Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)
- [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)
- [First Class Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)

Answer (score 0):

That's not even the question about react, that's simple js basics. I gonna explain on another subject, events function calls

```
document.addEventListener('change',(createHiveBackground));
document.addEventListener('change', (event)=>createHiveBackground(anotherParam));
```

The above both actions act the same, but the only difference how you coded `createHiveBackground` in first line your function handles by it own the incoming arguments as it would look like
`function createHiveBackground(event, anotherArg){}` because parent function ***addEventListener*** passes ***event*** as arguments in either cases as the first argument to the mentioned function.

But in the second case you coded the function which expects oneArgument only `function createHiveBackground(anotherArg){}` and you avoid conflicts between ***addEventListener*** and ***createHiveBackground*** so you use ***function in the middle***

Another your line about difference with it:

```
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground());
```

Your ***createHiveBackground*** is written like this:

```
function createHiveBackground() {return data}
```

to provide a data that *React.useState* waiting for. This executes your func at once.
But this will not work at

```
document.addEventListener('change', createHiveBackground())
```

because it will be executed right in 'compilation' when no event have been fired. One exception it may return another function which will be called at event firing.

```
function createHiveBackground(){ return function(event, anotherParam){doSomeStuff on event}
```

The last example just passes a function body which may be called later 
`()=>createHiveBackground`
it will not be invoked immediately

Coming back to your question hence React.useState expects some data - you may use any of these depending on ***createHiveBackground*** function implementation (the colleague above says:

```
//first two similar and used at lazy call
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground);
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(()=>createHiveBackground());

//the next must return a data to be passed to the state
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(createHiveBackground());

//nothing will happened because the function body will be passed but not executed
//function's body will be stored at the state
const [hive, setHive] = React.useState(()=>createHiveBackground);
```

Comment: 'Compilation'? I think, there is a better wording. Something like "immediately, even when the event was not fired".

Comment: @user6537157 you might edit my post yourself if you think it's may be rephrased better, that's why i put 'compile' word in the brackets, i know there no any common meaning of compilation in js

Comment: The last example assigns a function, it can be called as hive(), it wont throw an exception you should check it

Comment: @DennisVash sure, you're right, in case if we need to store the function body in the state